# How to render json data in angular 2

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I'm trying to output json data list. However I'm getting an error message `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`. When I checked the console log I could see the json being outputted.

**mydata.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class MyDataService {
  post = '';
  constructor(private http: Http) { 
  }
  fetchData(){
      return this.http.get('assets/page-content.json').map(
        (response) => response.json()
      ).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.post = data;
            console.log(this.post);
        }
      )
  }
}
```

**page-content.component.html**

```
<div class="search-results" infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="2" [infiniteScrollThrottle]="300" (scrolled)="onScroll()">
    <h1>Title: {{post.title}}</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sit amet dignissim nibh. Praesent tempus risus at metus finibus, at luctus nisi maximus. Sed enim urna, suscipit at dignissim eget, fermentum semper lacus. Donec nec ligula tristique, volutpat sem a, posuere nisl. Sed vehicula leo ut nulla maximus, eu mattis diam placerat.</p>
</div>
```

**page-content.json**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Sample title 1",
        "description": "<p class=\"abc\">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sit amet dignissim nibh. Praesent tempus risus at metus finibus, at luctus nisi maximus. Sed enim urna, suscipit at dignissim eget, fermentum semper lacus. Donec nec ligula tristique, volutpat sem a, posuere nisl. Sed vehicula leo ut nulla maximus, eu mattis diam placerat.</p>"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Sample title 2",
        "description": "<p class=\"abc\">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sit amet dignissim nibh. Praesent tempus risus at metus finibus, at luctus nisi maximus. Sed enim urna, suscipit at dignissim eget, fermentum semper lacus. Donec nec ligula tristique, volutpat sem a, posuere nisl. Sed vehicula leo ut nulla maximus, eu mattis diam placerat.</p>"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Sample title 3",
        "description": "<p class=\"abc\">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sit amet dignissim nibh. Praesent tempus risus at metus finibus, at luctus nisi maximus. Sed enim urna, suscipit at dignissim eget, fermentum semper lacus. Donec nec ligula tristique, volutpat sem a, posuere nisl. Sed vehicula leo ut nulla maximus, eu mattis diam placerat.</p>"
    }
]
```

Comment: `post` is an array?

Comment: Yes `post` is in array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not subscribe in the service. It will only return a subscription object not data.

```
  fetchData(){
      return this.http.get('assets/page-content.json').map(
        (response) => response.json()
      )
  }
```

And in your 
**PageContentComponent.ts**,
maybe in `ngOnInit`,

```
export class PageContentComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private newService: MyDataService) { }
  posts = '';
  ngOnInit() {
    this.newService.fetchData().subscribe(data=>{
      this.posts = data;
    });
  }     
}
```

And finally in you html,

```
 <div *ngIf="posts">
 <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
        {{ post.title}}
 </li>
 </div>
```

Comment: Good catch, was just about to write an answer when I noticed, it took a while to see it  :D